# How to convert bytes body to string using http header charset definition in camel RouteBuilder?

Tags: java, apache-camel

In a camel instance I would like to convert the body of a rest message to a string using the specified encoding of the HTTP header.

The route definition I came up with so far looks like the following:

```
    from("cxfrs:bean:rsServer")
    .convertBodyTo(String.class, header(Exchange.HTTP_CHARACTER_ENCODING).evaluate(refToCurrentExchange, String.class))
    .inOnly("activemq:jms:foo");
```

However I don't know how to evaluate the `Exchange.HTTP_CHARACTER_ENCODING` header in order to use its value as the target charset for `convertBodyTo`.

If the body isn't converted, the message send to the jms queue will be a jms bytes message, but I would like it to be a jms text message.

How can I use the `Exchange.HTTP_CHARACTER_ENCODING` value as an argument to `convertBodyTo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented a new processor to do the job:

```
public static final class ConvertBodyToStringProcessor implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception { // NOPMD
        new ConvertBodyProcessor(String.class, (String) new HeaderExpression(Exchange.HTTP_CHARACTER_ENCODING).evaluate(exchange)).process(exchange);
    }
}
```

now the definition of the route looks like this:

```
from("cxfrs:bean:rsServer")
.process(new ConvertBodyToStringProcessor())
.inOnly("activemq:jms:foo");
```